# Python: Create a new column based on different conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a dataset with different columns. It looks like that:

```
ID = [97,97,97,19,19,33,33,33,33,33,11] 
DATE = [2018-09,2018-09,2020-02,2021-01,2021-01,2017-04,2017-04,2017-04,2019-09,2019-09,2022-05] 
Destination_1 = [BRAZIL,BRAZIL,BRAZIL,ARGENTINA,MOROCCO,INDONESIA,USA,BRAZIL,EGYPT,LEBANON,USA] 
Destination_2 = [BRAZIL,URUGUAY,SINGAPORE,VENEZUELA,THAILAND,PERU,ECUADOR,USA,ALGERIA, EGYPT,CANADA]
```

I would like to create a new column OUTPUT based on the following condition:

*for each ID if at the same DATE at least one of the DESTINATION_1 equals DESTINATION_2 then the output sould be TRUE otherwise FALSE.*

The desired result for the OUTPUT column should then be:

```
OUTPUT=[TRUE, TRUE, FALSE , FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE]
```

meaning that if at the same DATE at least one destination is common to each ID then the condition is satisfied and the output is TRUE.

How could I do so? So far I tried:

```
   for sublist in df["ID"]:
  if (df["Destination_1"] == df["Destination_2"]).any():
    print("True")
  else :
    print("False")
```

but this doesn't work for me and I do not get how to add the second condition concerning the DATE without getting an error.

Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `groupby` and use `isin` to check value existence then `assign`

```py
out = (df.groupby(['ID', 'DATE'])
       .apply(lambda g: g.assign(OUTPUT=[g['Destination_1'].isin(g['Destination_2']).any()]*len(g))))
```

```
print(out)

    ID     DATE Destination_1 Destination_2  OUTPUT
0   97  2018-09        BRAZIL        BRAZIL    True
1   97  2018-09        BRAZIL       URUGUAY    True
2   97  2020-02        BRAZIL     SINGAPORE   False
3   19  2021-01     ARGENTINA     VENEZUELA   False
4   19  2021-01       MOROCCO      THAILAND   False
5   33  2017-04     INDONESIA          PERU    True
6   33  2017-04           USA       ECUADOR    True
7   33  2017-04        BRAZIL           USA    True
8   33  2019-09         EGYPT       ALGERIA    True
9   33  2019-09       LEBANON         EGYPT    True
10  11  2022-05           USA        CANADA   False
```

Comment: thanks for your help! It works perfectly, can I ask you where to find good documentation concerning the lambda function please?

Comment: @Cai I would refer to [How to Use Python Lambda Functions – Real Python](https://realpython.com/python-lambda/), but I don't why it needs to be registered to read now. Anyway, `lambda` function isn't really a much complicated concept any tutorial you find on the web I think is enough.